# What is the difference between a single-particle potential energy and an interaction?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, potential-energy, interactions, second-quantization

When we set up Hartree-Fock equations for atoms we work with the following Hamiltonian:

$\displaystyle{H=\sum_{i,j}a_i^\dagger \langle i|T|j\rangle a_j+\sum_{i,j} a_i^\dagger \langle i|U|j\rangle a_j +\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i,j,k,m}\langle i,j|V|k,m\rangle a_i^\dagger a_j^\dagger a_m a_k}$

Where Schwabl (*Advanced Quantum Mechanics*) says that $U$ is the potential the electrons feel due to the nucleus and $V$ is the Coulomb interaction. And here my question arises because well, both $U$ and $V$ are described by Coulomb interaction so, why $U$ term (electron-nucleus interaction) is treated as a single-particle operator and not as a two-particle operator as the case of $V$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the Hamiltonian does not contain the kinetic energy of the nucleus, so  U functions as an external potential. You could include the kinetic energy of the nucleus, but then you have an extra degree of freedom associated with free particle motion of the whole atom.

Comment: It might be useful to point out that this is known in literature as the [Born-Oppenheimer approximation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Born%E2%80%93Oppenheimer_approximation).

Comment: This is related with the distinction between coupling and interaction?